# Jquery Condition not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is when I uploaded an invalid file extension and invalid file size. It doesn't alert Invalid file type and file size but instead it alerts depending on what is the first file that meets the 2 condition.

For example when I uploaded `example.php` and another file that has greater than 2048 it will alert the invalid file type. Then vise versa.

What I want is if I uploaded `example.php` and another file that has greater than 2048 the output must be Invalid file type and file size.

Here is my code:

```
var fileextension = new RegExp("(.*?)\.(csv|doc|docx|gif|jpeg|jpg|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|txt|xls|xlxs|zip|mp3|mp4)$");
$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

for(var i=0; i<this.files.length; i++){
    var filename = this.files[i].name.toLowerCase();
    var fsize = this.files[i].size,
        fsize = fsize / 1024; // 1024 = 1mb
        if(fsize > 2048){
            $(this).val('');
            swal('Opps','Invalid file size','warning');
        }else if(!fileextension.test(filename)){
            $(this).val('');
            swal('Opps','Invalid file type','warning');
        }else if(!fileextension.test(filename) &&  fsize > 2048){
            $(this).val('');
            swal('Opps','Invalid file type and file size','warning');
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a temporary string with e.g. `message`, and change your `if` block like this:

```
var message = "";

if(fsize > 2048){
  message += "Invalid file size";
}

if(!fileextension.test(filename)) {
  message += message === "" ? "Invalid" : " and";
  message += " file type";
}
```

Then you can call `swal` like this:

```
if (message) {  // Checks if there is something in `message`
  $(this).val('');
  swal('Opps',message,'warning');
}
```

**Edit:**
Here is the updated answer (which is mentioned in the fiddle):

```
var fileextension = new RegExp("(.*?)\.(csv|doc|docx|gif|jpeg|jpg|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|txt|xls|xlxs|zip|mp3|mp4)$");

$('input[type=file]').change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase(),
    invalidType = false,
    invalidSize = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    var filename = this.files[i].name.toLowerCase();
    var fsize = this.files[i].size,
      fsize = fsize / 1024; // 1024 = 1mb

    if (fsize > 2048) {
      invalidSize = true;
    }

    if (!fileextension.test(filename)) {
      invalidType = true;
    }
  }

  var message = "";

  if (invalidType) {
    message += "Invalid type";
  }

  if (invalidSize) {
    message += (message === "" ? "" : " and") + " size";
  }

  if (message) {
    swal('Opps', message, 'warning');
  }

});
```

Comment: i tried your code i uploaded a php file and a file that is greater than 2048 and still it doesnt show the right error here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/ga9ht53e/6/

Comment: Well, can't really figure it out, but tried to open the link you gave, and it is working perfectly for me. Can you check again?

Comment: its working perfectly when you upload atleast 1 valid file extension and the other file is let say file size is greater than 2048 then it will alert that invalid file size. and vice versa. but if i uploaded invalid file extension such as .php file and a valid file with greater than 2048 size it will not alert "Invalid file type and file size"

Comment: What you want to do needs to be done after the loop has completed. Have a look [at this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ga9ht53e/7/).

Answer (score 0):

What's happens is that the first `if` condition that evaluates to `true` gets executed, and the program does not evaluate the rest. In your case, this makes the last condition in your `if else` loop inaccessible. If you want your last condition to be evaluated first, then move it up - something like this:

```
var fileextension = new RegExp("(.*?)\.(csv|doc|docx|gif|jpeg|jpg|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|txt|xls|xlxs|zip|mp3|mp4)$");
$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

for(var i=0; i<this.files.length; i++){
    var filename = this.files[i].name.toLowerCase();
    var fsize = this.files[i].size,
        fsize = fsize / 1024; // 1024 = 1mb
        if(!fileextension.test(filename) &&  fsize > 2048){
            $(this).val('');
            swal('Opps','Invalid file type and file size','warning');
        }
        else if(fsize > 2048){
            $(this).val('');
            swal('Opps','Invalid file size','warning');
        }
        else if(!fileextension.test(filename)){
            $(this).val('');
            swal('Opps','Invalid file type','warning');
        }
}
```

**Edit**- If you want your output to be based on the status of all the files as a group, and not individual files, then obviously you cannot process your output inside the loop. You would need to do something like this:

```
 var fileextension = new RegExp("(.*?)\.(csv|doc|docx|gif|jpeg|jpg|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|txt|xls|xlxs|zip|mp3|mp4)$");
$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

var sizeError=false;
var extensionError=false;

for(var i=0; i<this.files.length; i++){
    var filename = this.files[i].name.toLowerCase();
    var fsize = this.files[i].size,
        fsize = fsize / 1024; // 1024 = 1mb
        if(fsize > 2048){
            sizeError=true;
        }
        if(!fileextension.test(filename)){
            extensionError=true;
        }
}
```

Now use these boolean values `extensionError` and `sizeError` outside the `for` loop to check and process the output.

Comment: i already tried that and the output is invalid file size. which the first value that pass to my array is greater than 2048 and the 2nd value passed to my array is invalid file type.

Comment: i tried the edited one and still it didnt get the error. here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/y3q29ocp/5/ and also now i encoutered when i tried to upload to upload a single it doesnt validate unlike here in my other code  jsfiddle.net/ga9ht53e/6